# TypedQuery is not working as expected

Tags: jpa, openjpa

Iam running into below issue

```
String queryString = SELECT 
   a.field1 as f1,a.field2 as f2,b.field3 as f3,c.field4 as f4
FROM 
   Entity1 a,  Entity2 b, Entity3 c
WHERE 
   a.cf1 = b.cf2 
   AND a.cf4 = c.cf3 
   AND a.fieldn = ?1
```

Defined below entity to hold above ResultSet

```
public class Entity1 {
  public String f1,f2,f3;
   Getters & Setters
}

List<Entity1> list = new ArrayList<>();
        TypedQuery<Entity1> typedQuery = bowbEntityManager.createQuery(queryString, Entity1.class);
        typedQuery.setParameter("fieldn", "blah");

    list = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

Iam getting ClassCastException.
Above "list" returned as object[] for each fields
i can access values by obj[0], obj[1],....

Can anyone point out the mistake here? I want to retrieve the resultset as List.

Comment: Can you post full error stack please?

Comment: <openjpa-2.4.0-r422266:1674604 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: There was an error packing the projection and/or aggregate results of the query into result type "class com.ss.dd.xx.Entity1".  See the nested Throwable exception for details.

FailedObject: String queryString = SELECT 
   a.field1 as f1,a.field2 as f2,b.field3 as f3,c.field4 as f4
FROM 
   Entity1 a,  Entity2 b, Entity3 c

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ResultPacker.packUserType(ResultPacker.java:279)

Comment: give full, real code. Way Yoy put this fragments of code is unbelievable for me